# Call to `thisCap()` segfaults

Tags: capnproto

I am playing with the `calculator-server.c++` sample, where I try to extract `thisCap()` to have a capability to the server from outside. Because `thisCap()` is `protected`, I wrote my own public `getCapability()`:

```cpp
class CalculatorImpl final: public Calculator::Server {
  // Implementation of the Calculator Cap'n Proto interface.

public:
  Calculator::Client getCapability() {
      return thisCap();
  }
```

Then I create the server and call `getCapability()` from my main:

```cpp
  auto calculatorImpl = kj::heap<CalculatorImpl>();
  auto myCapability = calculatorImpl->getCapability();
```

But this segfaults:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055555573c847 in capnp::Capability::Server::thisCap() ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000055555573c847 in capnp::Capability::Server::thisCap() ()
#1  0x000055555573c93d in Calculator::Server::thisCap() ()
#2  0x000055555573e541 in CalculatorImpl::getCapability() ()
#3  0x0000555555739a98 in main ()
```

Following the source, I end up on [this](https://github.com/capnproto/capnproto/blob/f23ea50913d18425b2b6318e76cbeaa6ce30120c/c%2B%2B/src/capnp/capability.h#L993-L995):

```cpp
Capability::Client Capability::Server::thisCap() {
  return Client(thisHook->addRef());
}
```

So it seems like `thisHook` is a nullptr, which makes sense since that's [how it is initialized](https://github.com/capnproto/capnproto/blob/f23ea50913d18425b2b6318e76cbeaa6ce30120c/c%2B%2B/src/capnp/capability.h#L454).

I just don't really get at which point it get initialized ([this](https://github.com/capnproto/capnproto/blob/f23ea50913d18425b2b6318e76cbeaa6ce30120c/c%2B%2B/src/capnp/capability.h#L430-L438) explains when it is definitely not initialized).

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`thisCap()` only works after at least one `Client` object has been created pointing at your server object. To create that initial `Client`, you can simply declare a variable of the client type and initialize it to your server object, like so:

```
Calculator::Client cap = kj::heap<CalculatorImpl>();
```

If you want to keep a reference to the underlying server object even after constructing a `Client`, you can do something like:

```
kj::Own<CalculatorImpl> server = kj::heap<CalculatorImpl>();
CalculatorImpl& ref = *server;
Calculator::Client cap = kj::mv(server);
```

Note that once the first `Client` has been created, the server will be destroyed as soon as there are no longer any `Client`s pointing to it (including remote `Client`s). So if you want to make sure your reference stays live, make sure you also keep a copy of the `Client`.

Normally, `thisCap()` is used inside the implementation of RPC methods. It's unusual to expose it to external callers in the way you have with your `getCapability()` method. This is because if the caller isn't already holding a `Client` pointing to the object, then it has no way to know if the object still exists, and so it would be unsafe to call a method like `getCapability()`.

Comment: But then I cannot use that `server` anymore to create something like: `capnp::EzRpcServer rpcServer(server, argv[1]);`, right? It seems like `EzRpcServer` cannot take a reference, but on the other hand now the `Client` has the ownership. Maybe I don't think it correctly, I was trying to get some kind of `kj::shared_ptr` ^^. Should I bypass `EzRpcServer` and create mine with the lower-level API?

Comment: uho! Actually I can pass `ref` to `EzRpcServer`, because it wants a `Client` \o/. There is something not-so-intuitive to me about this Server/Client difference. I was not expecting to be able to cast a Server as a Client, and it already felt weird before to pass a server to `EzRpcServer(Capability::Client, ...)` (in my mental model, I was actually passing it a server).